# Nightly Build is not working with Dollars and Cents formatting

Tags: orbeon, xforms

We are using Orbeon 3.9 PE, and created forms with calculated fields using the *Dollars and Cents* control. Now we are in the process of replacing Orbeon 3.9 PE we have found the following issue with the Orbeon nightly build of 06/16/2011:

1. While testing we found that all the calculations and the formatting are not working.
2. When we populate a PDF template the dollars and cents values are not passed to the PDF.

How can we solve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

This was a [bug](http://forge.ow2.org/tracker/index.php?func=detail&aid=316015&group_id=168&atid=350207). It is now [fixed](https://github.com/orbeon/orbeon-forms/commit/bdd7b75b14bd58c50994dea1d5fc0b8f017feae9).

Comment: BTW, good catch. Nightly builds are temporarily offline, but you can grab a build with this fix from http://goo.gl/SzFFN.

Comment: Thank you very much for the update. We are using Orbeon PE version, but you provided me the Orbeon CE version. If you could can you please provide us the latest Orbeon PE version. Note:Orbeon PE Nightly Build still shows as 06.15.2011 version.